# Implement solution to get stable gdal and fiona library versions on Windows

Tags: python, geopandas, gdal, fiona

I am trying to read a shapefile using python's geopandas in vscode. I successfully installed geopandas using conda, but when I use gpd.read_file, I get the following error output:

```
ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly.
Importing fiona resulted in: DLL load failed while importing ogrext: The specified module could not be founds
```

I am trying to follow the following solution: [ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly. Importing fiona resulted in:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521550/importerror-the-read-file-function-requires-the-fiona-package-but-it-is-no)

Apparently, I was using below versions of GDAL and fiona combinations which didn't work for me.

> GDAL-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

> Fiona-1.8.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

> I had to uninstall the above versions and install the below versions instead. This resolved the issue.

> GDAL-3.2.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

> Fiona‑1.8.19‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Should I uninstall gdal and fiona using `pip uninstall gdal fiona` and then use `pip install <version>` to install the working versions? Also, since the post is from Oct 2021, should I still use the mentioned versions?

Comment: Why are you installing `fiona` and `gdal` using pip (wheels), but `geopandas` using conda? Conda will almost always prevent incompatible builds to be installed simultaneously, I would start by installing everything that you need using conda as much as possible.

Comment: I installed these packages using miniconda, but had issues with geopandas. I found a solution that said to reinstall older compatible versions of fiona and gdal. Following your recommendation, I will uninstall all packages and then purely install packages with conda to see if it works.