# geopandas to_crs() return ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size

Tags: python, geopandas, epsg

**How can I convert this geodataframe with polygons in it from epsg:32748 to epsg:4326?**

I have a geodataframe called poi_shp_utm_buffered which looks like this

```
|   |                                   PlaceID | Official_N | Primary__1 | Full_Stree | Overall_Sc |             X |            Y |                                          geometry |
|--:|------------------------------------------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|--------------:|-------------:|--------------------------------------------------:|
| 0 | 360qqu5b-409576faa57505ae78aa1cd551661af6 |          a |          1 |          1 |          2 | 709469.120296 | 9.299854e+06 | POLYGON ((709479.120 9299853.811, 709479.072 9... |
| 1 | 360qqu5b-5ec43f6ad613e60c15e3c4779f9c003d |          b |          1 |          1 |          2 | 709369.905462 | 9.299615e+06 | POLYGON ((709379.905 9299615.157, 709379.857 9... |
| 2 | 360qqu5b-7c11918bf9754eb6841c838f3337b783 |          c |          2 |          2 |          1 | 707546.465569 | 9.300030e+06 | POLYGON ((707556.466 9300030.011, 707556.417 9... |
```

When I extract the crs, it gives me

```
>>> poi_shp_utm_buffered.to_crs

<Projected CRS: EPSG:32748>
Name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 48S
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World - S hemisphere - 102°E to 108°E - by country
- bounds: (102.0, -80.0, 108.0, 0.0)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 48S
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

The error:

```
poi_shp_utm_buffered.to_crs(4326)
```

```
ProjError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15024\2103948270.py in 
      2 # __ = poi_shp_utm_buffered
      3 
----> 4 __ = poi_shp_utm_buffered.drop(columns = ['X','Y']).to_crs(4326)

c:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg, inplace)
   1362         else:
   1363             df = self.copy()
-> 1364         geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
   1365         df.geometry = geom
   1366         if not inplace:

c:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
   1122         """
   1123         return GeoSeries(
-> 1124             self.values.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg), index=self.index, name=self.name
   1125         )
   1126 

c:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py in to_crs(self, crs, epsg)
    777         transformer = Transformer.from_crs(self.crs, crs, always_xy=True)
    778 
--> 779         new_data = vectorized.transform(self.data, transformer.transform)
...
    432             iny,

pyproj/_transformer.pyx in pyproj._transformer._Transformer._transform()

ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size
```

This is my geopandas version

```
>>> gpd.show_versions()

SYSTEM INFO
-----------
python     : 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable : c:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\python.exe
machine    : Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0

GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO
---------------------
GEOS       : None
GEOS lib   : None
GDAL       : 3.6.2
GDAL data dir: c:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\lib\site-packages\pyogrio\gdal_data\
PROJ       : 6.2.1
PROJ data dir: C:\Users\arasyidi\Anaconda3\envs\python_ds_gis\Library\share\proj

PYTHON DEPENDENCIES
-------------------
geopandas  : 0.12.2
numpy      : 1.21.5
pandas     : 1.4.3
pyproj     : 2.6.1.post1
shapely    : 1.8.4
fiona      : None
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : None
matplotlib : 3.5.2
mapclassify: 2.5.0
pygeos     : 0.9
pyogrio    : 0.5.1
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : 11.0.0
rtree      : 0.9.7
```

Ps. if I check using `conda list` on my environment, I actually have fiona installed, but somehow the gpd.show_version can detect it.

Comment: i get the same error from a `to_crs` call in my code running geopandas 0.12.2, but not on my other computer that is running geopandas 0.10.2

Comment: see discussion here: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2874 . reinstalling to the latest versions of all dependencies solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

updating `proj` and `pyproj` to latest as suggest in the github error report fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

updating `pyproj` led to other errors for me (specifically this one: [ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly. Importing fiona resulted in:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521550/importerror-the-read-file-function-requires-the-fiona-package-but-it-is-no))

I got it to work by downgrading `shapely` to version 1.8.4 as suggested here:
https://cleanenergyfutures.insightworks.com/pages/9119.html